# after clicking a button of sweet alert call php file

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I am trying to call a `php` file after clicking a button in the sweet alert. This function is the confirmation of Logging the account. Sample process is when you log out the active account, there will be a pop-up message that was the sweet alert, and if you click OK button, then it should have destroyed the session of the user. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:swal({title:'Logout', 
text:'Do you want to logout this Account?'
    , icon:'warning', 
    buttons: true, 
    dangerMode: true}).then((willOUT) => {
    if (willOUT) {
          url: 'page_logout.php', {
          icon: 'success',
        });
      }
    });" 
    class="nav-item dropdown-item">             
    Log out
</a>
```

[see the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXaNc.png)

Comment: What is it doing right now? What do you see in your javascript console if you hit F12 while you try it? What happens if you use <button onClick> instead of <a href>?

Comment: @mkaatman i have attached the picture of the console sir. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help you. It can take you to page_logout.php
And there is also some error in your swal code which you have written in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="a_id">Logout</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#a_id").click(function(){

                    swal({title:'Logout', 
                        text:'Do you want to logout this Account?', 
                        icon:'warning', 
                        buttons: true, 
                        dangerMode: true
                    })
                    .then((willOUT) => {
                            if (willOUT) {
                                  window.location.href = 'page_logout.php', {
                                  icon: 'success',
                                }
                              }
                    });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or if you want to show message in the same page in which there is logout button, then instead of url in your question do ajax request to page_logout.php. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sir?? Should I put this inside the `href`?

Comment: i have updated my answer, now you can check it there, hope it will help you now

Answer (score 0):

try js:

```
<button type="button" onclick="logout('<?php echo $SESSION['user']['userId'] ?> ')" class="btn-danger">logout</button>
function logout(id) {
    swal({
        title: "Do you want to logout this Account?",
        type: "error",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true
    },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    userLogout(id);
                }
            });
}

function userLogout(id) {
    $.post(base_url + "fileName/method_name", {id: id}, function (data) {
        if (data === "1") {
            }
         else if (data === "0") {
            swal("", "Error to logout user.", "warning");
        } else {
            swal("", data[0], "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logout event with function

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.8.2/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<a onClick="logout()">Logout</a>
<script>
function logout(){
 swal({
  title: 'Logout',
  text: 'Do you want to logout this Account?',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No.'
}).then(() => {
  if (result.value) {
    // Call ajax page_logout.php File
  } else {
    // Close alert
  }
});

}
OR 
functio logout() {
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(function() {
    swal(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  })
}
</script>
```